# Positioning views in Horizontal Scroll View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I'm trying to build a point-and-click adventure for Android without using any pre-written engine, but I'm stuck in a really crucial point!

I have a `HorizontalScrollView` bigger than the screen, so the user can scroll left and right in portrait mode to search around rooms, now what I need is to insert items that the player can use inside this View.

I'm trying to use static `ImageView`, but I'm really confused on how to insert Views in an absolute position inside the `HorizontalScrollView`. All I know is that Android manages Views location relative to other views (align on top, next to, bottom of), but what I use if I need to position a View in a specified position using specific coordinates without worrying that the image will be misplaced in a different screen size for other Android devices?

I really am confused on how position views in Android :/

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating your own view instead of abusing HSV.
Custom views, doDraw() method, canvas and even gesture detection is not that hard.

Here is a link that will help you with basics, simple viewport implementation for android with scrolling via key events: http://sonnygill.net/android/android-viewport/

Answer (score 0):

> what I use if I need to position a View in a specified position using specific coordinates without worrying that the image will be misplaced in a different screen size for other Android devices

Actually, that's exactly the reason `ViewGroup` (layouts) were created. 
You should choose the right layout based on your requirements. 
If you do want to position the views by yourself, you can create your own custom `ViewGroup` by extending one of the view group classes and override the `onLayout(...)` and `onMeasure(...)` methods which are used to position and measure child views (in you case, probably the `ImageView`s) respectively.
You can use [this example](https://code.google.com/p/devoxx-schedule/source/browse/devoxx-android-client/src/net/peterkuterna/android/apps/devoxxsched/ui/widget/FlowLayout.java?name=422c381967&r=422c38196733ba3c54eb44418160e248ee1aea86) of `FlowLayout` as a reference on how you can write your own custom `ViewGroup`.

Please note that if your content is bigger than the screen as you mentioned, the HorizontalScrollView should be a parent of a single child (which should be the ViewGroup containing your images).